# Recovering lost changes after reverting bad merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I'm relatively new to Git and made a (stupid) mistake after misunderstanding a help article and I am not sure how to fully fix the issue using Git rather than manually reintroducing the changes to the target branch.

```
S---sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4---R1---M5---sc5
 \                         \  /         /
  T1-------------------M2---M3--------R2
   \               \  /
    F---fc1---fc2---M1
```

Some notes: `S` is the main branch in this scenario, `T1` is the team branch pulled from `S`, and `F` is my feature branch pulled from `T1`.

I have auto-merges set up, so when commits are made to the `T1` branch, they are run through continuous integration and then auto-merged up to `S`. There was one file in the `T1` branch that was having merge conflicts with `S` from another team member's commit, so I decided to fix that once I was done with my work on `F`.

I merged `T1` into `F` (`M1`), then `F` into `T1` (`M2`). Given the issues I've had in the past with merge conflict resolutions not behaving how I expect, I thought I'd try something new: merging just the conflicting file from `S` into `T1`, solving the merge conflict there, removing all of the other files from the merge, and then allowing continuous integration to merge everything up to `S`

I started a merge from `S` to `T1` (`M3`) without committing, addressed the conflict, removed the other (~200) files from the merge, then committed. This auto-merged to `S` (`M4`).

I noticed immediately that excluding those ~200 files looked to have wiped the changes out entirely, which equated to about a month's worth of work across 2 teams. I (incorrectly) decided the best course of action was to act swiftly and revert the merge commits `M4` and `M3` before my mistake got into anyone else's local repos. I first reverted `M4` (`R1`) and once that was committed I reverted `M3` (`R2`). I figured that was the right order because I wasn't sure if the other way around would have introduced issues when the auto-merge kicked in. Eventually `R2` was committed and auto-merged to `S` (`M5`).

This solved the issue of everyone else's changes being wiped out, but all of my changes in `F` plus the file that originally had the merge conflict were gone from `S`. I was able to commit the single file's changes directly to `S` (`sc5`), but the changes in `F` are a lot more complex. They live in `T1` still, but since they were reverted from `S` as part of `R1`, I cannot just commit them back.

I've spent the better part of the day trying to figure out how to best get these changes up to `S`, but `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` don't seem like they will do what I need, though I am very aware that I can be wrong on that. If anyone much better at Git than I am could suggest at least a starting point, that would be amazing. Thanks!

**Edit:** Removed unhelpful/confusing points from graph. `M2` did not auto-merge up to `S` because of the merge conflict I attempted to resolve with `M3`.

**Edit 2:** After reading through the fantastic explanation from torek, I began attempting a rebase. I had forgotten that I had merged the `T1` branch into the `F` branch multiple times throughout the history of `F` because of how much time this feature branch spanned. This meant there were many, many merge conflicts to resolve.

At torek's response to this, I attempted a merge squash. My initial thought is I need to merge the new branch from the merge squash up to the `T1` branch and then merge the `T1` branch up to `S`, but I ran into the same issue where it doesn't see the changes. I assume this is because the changes already exist in `T1` so it was basically just feeding the same, previously-reverted changes back into `S`, which doesn't want them.

**Edit 3:** Thanks to the very well-explained, detailed answer from torek (thank you so much!), I am going through with the merge squash and then merging the result of that up to the `S` branch after resolving the conflicts.

Comment: It might help if you linked to whatever this Octopus CI thing is. Your graph drawing is rather nice too, but doesn't reflect how Git actually works internally—Git's branch names merely identify *tip* commits, with the set of commits contained by that branch changing dynamically as the graph grows. I would have to make a bunch of assumptions here...

Comment: Mentioning Octopus wasn't helpful, so I removed it. Re: CI - I just meant it ran through our continuous integration builds, so I fixed that too. As for the graph, the commits that I added in there (sc1, tc1, etc.) were just to demonstrate that activity was happening on those branches between merges. I'm not familiar enough with Git internally to graph that out - I just used it as a visual aid as I've seen done in the documentation and guides I've read.

Comment: OK, but you said "auto-merges" (as part of the CI system, I assume), yet you show in your drawing several commits between merges. For instance there's tc2 pointing back to tc1, with no merges going from the top to the middle row. (Git graphs with time increasing towards the right should be read right-to-left: Git starts at the ends—those tip commits I mentioned—and works backwards.) The end result here is that I'm not sure what to assume about your actual Git graph. Since the graph controls what merges do, this is important.

Comment: Good point, thank you for your patience. I have edited the graph and explained the M2 merge in the edit. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: OK, I think it all makes sense to me now. One more question: is any of this pushed / published anywhere, or can you remove and rewrite a lot of these commits safely? (Technically those two aren't mutually exclusive, but a simple way to think about Git commits is that if you haven't let anyone else see them yet, you can remove them without worrying about it.)

Comment: The original mistake of wiping out changes made it out to remote, so the reverts are all out on remote as well. This happened yesterday and since then several new operations have taken place on the `T1` and `S` branches. My changes in `F` still exist in `T1` and I could manually remake the changes directly to `S` but that feels a little awkward. I understand I may have no choice, though.

Comment: OK, in these situations it's generally just best to "confess", as it were: leave the mistakes out for all to view. The problem with trying to undo them—to rewrite history—is that you have to get *everyone else* to base *their* histories on the new, rewritten history. So we should view this as "how to convince Git to see these again".

Comment: Right, that's what I'm hoping to get to here. I'm not looking to rewrite the history (I would actually prefer not to), I'm just trying to see if there's a way to get my changes that are in `T1` up to `S` so their path up to `S` will still go `F` --> `T1` --> `S` instead of `F` --> `T1` and then magically appearing in `S` because I manually added them there.

Comment: (this is going to take a while to write, and I have to head home now, just FYI - not sure when I can get back to it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite long, so feel free to skip over sections you already know (or scroll all the way to the end).  Each section has setup information to explain what's going on, or what we are doing, in later ones.

#### Introduction-y bits

Let me start by re-drawing this graph (which I think is sort of a partial graph, but it contains the key commits we need) the way I prefer:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4---R1---M5---sc5   <-- branch-S
  \                        \  /         /
   T0-------------o----M2---M3--------R2   <---- branch-T1
    \              \  /
    F0--fc1---fc2---M1   <------------------- branch-F
```

Here, the *branch names* are `branch-S`, `branch-T1`, and `branch-F`, and these names currently identify commits whose hash IDs are something unpronounceable and impossible for humans to remember, but we are calling `sc5`, `R2`, and `M1` respectively.  Any `o` nodes are commits that are not especially distinguished in any way, and may actually represent some arbitrary number of commits.  The named `fc<number>`s are some set of commits on the feature branch, with the `M<number>` commits being merges.  I renamed the first commits `S0`, `T0`, and `F0` just to tell them apart from the branch names.

Some merges are made manually:

```
$ git checkout <branch-name>
$ git merge [options] <other-branch>
... fix up conflicts if necessary, and git commit (or git merge --continue)
```

Other merges are made by software and happen only if there are no conflicts.  The `R` commits are from running:

```
git checkout <branch>
git revert -m 1 <hash ID of some M commit>
```

where `<branch>` was either `T1` or `S`, and `-m 1` is because you always have to tell `git revert` which parent to use when reverting a merge, and it's almost always parent #1.

#### Making commits moves a branch name

The simplest Git commit graph is a straight line, with one branch name, typically `master`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here, we need to mention Git's *index*.  The index is perhaps best described as the place where Git builds the *next* commit to make.  It initially contains every file as saved in the current commit (here `C`): you check out this commit, populating the index and work-tree with the files from commit `C`.  The name `master` points to this commit, and the name `HEAD` is attached to the name `master`.

You then modify files in the work-tree, use `git add` to copy them back into the index, use `git add` to copy *new* files into the index if needed, and run `git commit`.  Making a new commit works by freezing these index copies into a snapshot.  Git then adds the snapshot metadata—your name and email, your log message, and so on—along with the current commit's hash ID, so that the new commit points back to the existing commit.  The result is:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D
```

with the new commit, with its new unique hash ID, just hanging out in midair, with nothing to remember it.  So, the *last* step of making a new commit is to write the new commit's hash ID into the branch name:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and now the current commit is `D`, and the index and the current commit match.  If you `git add`-ed all the files in the work-tree, that too matches the current commit and the index.  If not, you can `git add` more files and commit again, making the name `master` point to new commit `E`, and so on.  In any case, the (single) parent of the new commit is whatever the current commit *was*.

#### About merges

Let me outline how `git merge` actually works.  It's very simple in some cases and some ways, and let's use the simplest true-merge case to start with.  Consider a graph that looks like this:

```
          o--...--L   <-- mainline (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--...--R   <-- feature
```

We have run `git checkout mainline; git merge feature`, so we are telling Git to merge branch `feature` / commit `R` into branch `mainline` / commit `L`.  To do this, Git must first find the *merge base* commit.  The merge base is, roughly speaking, the "nearest" commit common to—i.e., *reachable from*—both branches.  In this simple case, we start at `L` and walk backwards to older commits, and start at `R` and walk backwards, and the first place we meet is commit `*`, so that's the merge base.

(For much more about reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

Having found the merge base, Git needs to turn both the `L` (left-side / local / `--ours`) and `R` (right-side / remote / `--theirs`) snapshots into change-sets.  These change-sets tell Git what we did, on `mainline`, since the merge base `*`, and what they did, on `feature`, since the merge base.  These three commits all have hash IDs, which are the real names of the three commits, so Git can internally run the equivalent of:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-L>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-R>   # what they changed
```

The merge simply *combines* the two sets of changes, and applies the combined set to the files in the snapshot in `*`.

When all goes well, Git makes the new commit in the usual way, except that the new commit has *two* parents.  This makes the current branch to point to the new merge commit:

```
          o--...--L
         /         \
...--o--*           M   <-- mainline (HEAD)
         \         /
          o--...--R   <-- feature
```

The first parent of `M` is `L`, and the second is `R`.  This is why reverts almost always use parent #1, and why `git log --first-parent` only "sees" the mainline branch, traversing from `M` up to `L` while ignoring the `R` branch entirely.  (Note that the word *branch* here refers to the structure of the graph, rather than branch *names* like `feature`: at this point, we can delete the *name* `feature` entirely.  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

#### When things go wrong

A merge will stop, with a *merge conflict*, if the two change-sets overlap in a "bad way".  In particular, suppose that the base-vs-L says to change line 75 of file `F`, and the base-vs-R *also* says to change line 75 of file `F`.  If both change-sets say to make the *same* change, Git is OK with this: the combination of the two changes is to make the change once.  But if they say to make *different* changes, Git declares a merge conflict.  In this case, Git will stop after doing whatever it can on its own, and make you clean up the mess.

Since there are three inputs, Git will, at this point, leave *all three* versions of file `F` in the index.  Normally the index has one copy of each file to be committed, but during this conflict resolution phase, it has up to three copies.  (The "up to" part is because you can have other kinds of conflicts, which I won't go into here for space reasons.)  Meanwhile, in the *work-tree* copy of file `F`, Git leaves its approximation to the merge, with either two, or all three, sets of lines in the work-tree file with `<<<<<<<` / `>>>>>>>` markers around them.  (To get all three, set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.  I prefer this mode for resolving conflicts.)

As you have seen, you can resolve these conflicts any way you like.  Git assumes that whatever you do is the *right* way to resolve the problem: that this produces the exactly-correct final merged files, or lack of files in some cases.

Whatever you do, though, the final merge—assuming you don't abort it, and are not using one of the non-merge-y variants of merge—still makes the same result in the graph, and whatever you put in the index, by resolving the conflicts, is the result of the merge.  That's the new snapshot in the merge commit.

#### More-complex merge bases

When the graph is very simple like the one above, the merge base is easy to see.  But graphs don't stay simple, and yours isn't.  The merge base for a graph that has some merges in it is trickier.  Consider, e.g., just the following fragment:

```
 ...--sc4----M4---R1
         \  /
...--M2---M3--------R2
```

If `R1` and `R2` are two tip commits, what is their merge base?  The answer is `M3`, not `sc4`.  The reason is that while `M3` and `sc4` are both commits that are reachable by starting at both `R1` and `R2` and working backwards, `M3` is "closer" to `R2` (one step back).  The distance from `R1` to either `M3` or `sc4` is two hops—go to `M4`, then go back one more step—but the distance from `R2` to `M3` is one hop and the distance from `R2` to `sc4` is two hops.  So `M3` is "lower" (in graph terms) and therefore wins the contest.

(Fortunately, your graph has no cases where there is a tie.  If there *is* a tie, Git's default approach is to merge all the tied commits, two at a time, to produce a "virtual merge base", which is in fact an actual, albeit temporary, commit.  It then uses this temporary commit made by merging the merge bases.  This is the *recursive* strategy, which gets its name from the fact that Git recursively merges the merge bases to get a merge base.  You can choose instead the *resolve* strategy, which simply picks one of the bases at seemingly-random—whichever base pops out at the front of the algorithm.  There's rarely any advantage to that: the recursive method usually either does the same thing, or is an improvement over randomly selecting a winner.)

The key takeaway here is that **making a merge commit changes which commit *future* merges will choose as their merge base**.  This is important even when making simple merges, which is why I put it in boldface.  It's why we make merge commits, as opposed to squash-"merge" operations that aren't merges.  (But squash merges are still useful, as we will see in a bit.)

#### Introducing the problem: what went wrong (so you can avoid it in the future)

With the above out of the way, now we can look at the real problem.  Let's start with this (edited slightly to use the updated commit and branch names):

> I merged `branch-T1` into `branch-F` (`M1`), then `branch-F` into `branch-T1` (`M2`).

I assume here that merging `fc2` (as the then-tip of `branch-F`) and `o` (as the then-tip of `branch-T1`) went well, and Git was able to make `M1` on its own.  As we saw earlier, merging is really based not on *branches* but on *commits*.  It's the creation of a new commit that adjust the branch names.  So this created `M1`, so that `branch-F` pointed to `M1`.  `M1` itself pointed back to the existing tip of `branch-T1`—a commit I've now marked `o`—as its second parent, with `fc2` as its first parent.  Git figures out the correct *contents* for this commit by `git diff`-ing the contents of `T0`, the merge base, against `o` and against `fc2`:

```
T0-------------o   <-- branch-T1
 \
 F0--fc1---fc2   <--- branch-F (HEAD)
```

With all going well, Git now makes `M1` on its own:

```
T0-------------o   <-- branch-T1
 \              \
 F0--fc1---fc2---M1   <--- branch-F (HEAD)
```

Now you `git checkout branch-T1` and `git merge --no-ff branch-F` (without `--no-ff` Git will just do a fast-forward, which is not what is in the picture), so Git finds the merge base of `o` and `M1`, which is `o` itself.  This merge is easy: the difference from `o` to `o` is nothing, and nothing plus the difference from `o` to `M1` equals the contents of `M1`.  So `M2`, as a snapshot, is exactly the same as `M1`, and Git easily creates it:

```
T0-------------o----M2   <-- branch-T1 (HEAD)
 \              \  /
 F0--fc1---fc2---M1   <--- branch-F
```

So far, so good, but now things start to go really wrong:

> There was one file in the `T1` branch that was having merge conflicts with `S` ... Given the issues I've had in the past with merge conflict resolutions not behaving how I expect, I thought I'd try something new: merging just the conflicting file from `S` into `T1`, solving the merge conflict there, removing all of the other files from the merge, and then allowing continuous integration to merge everything up to `S`.

So, what you did at this point is:

```
git checkout branch-T1
git merge branch-S
```

which stopped with a merge conflict.  The graph at this point is the same as the one above, but with some more context:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4   <-- branch-S
  \
   T0-------------o----M2   <-- branch-T1 (HEAD)
    \              \  /
    F0--fc1---fc2---M1   <-- branch-F
```

The merge operation finds the merge base (`S0`), diffs that against the two tip commits (`M2` and `sc4`), combines the resulting changes, and applies them to the contents of `S0`.  The one conflicted file is now in the index as the three input copies, and in the work-tree as Git's effort at merging, but with conflict markers.  Meanwhile all the *unconflicted* files are in the index, ready to be frozen.

Alas, you now remove some files (`git rm`) during the conflicted merge.  This removes the files from the index and work-tree both.  The resulting commit, `M3`, will say that the correct way to combine commits `M2` and `sc4` based on merge-base `S0` is to remove those files.  (This of course was the mistake.)

> This auto-merged to `S` (`M4`).

Here, I assume this means that the system, using whatever pre-programmed rule it has, did the equivalent of:

```
git checkout branch-S
git merge --no-ff branch-T1
```

which found the merge base of commits `sc4` (tip of `branch-S`) and `M3`, which is `M3`, the same way that the merge base of `o` and `M1` was `M1` earlier.  So the new commit, `M4`, matches `M3` in terms of content, at which point we have:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4   <-- branch-S
  \                        \  /
   T0-------------o----M2---M3   <-- branch-T1
    \              \  /
    F0--fc1---fc2---M1   <-- branch-F
```

> I noticed immediately that excluding those ~200 files looked to have wiped the changes out entirely, which equated to about a month's worth of work across 2 teams. I (incorrectly) decided the best course of action was to act swiftly and revert the merge commits `M4` and `M3` before my mistake got into anyone else's local repos. I first reverted `M4` (`R1`) and once that was committed I reverted `M3` (`R2`).

Actually, this was a fine thing to do!  It gets the right *content*, which is pretty useful when you do it immediately.  Using `git checkout branch-s && git revert -m 1 branch-S` (or `git revert -m 1 <hash-of-M4>`) to create `R1` from `M4` basically undoes the merge in terms of content, so that:

```
git diff <hash-of-sc4> <hash-of-R1>
```

should produce nothing at all.  Likewise, using `git checkout branch-T1 && git revert -m 1 branch-T1` (or the same with the hash) to create `R2` from `M3` undoes that merge in terms of content: comparing `M2` and `R2`, you should see identical content.

#### Undoing a merge undoes the *contents*, but not the *history*

The problem now is that Git believes that all the changes in your feature branch are correctly incorporated.  Any `git checkout branch-T1` or `git checkout branch-S` followed by `git merge <any commit within branch-F>` will look at the graph, following the backwards-pointing links from commit to commit, and see that this commit within `branch-F`—such as `fc2` or `M1`—is *already merged*.

The trick to getting them in is to make a *new* commit that does the same thing that the commit-sequence from `F0` through `M1` does, that's *not* already merged.  The easiest—though ugliest—way to do that is to use `git merge --squash`.  The harder, and perhaps better, way to do that is to use `git rebase --force-rebase` to make a *new* feature branch.  (Note: this option has three spellings and the easiest one to type is `-f`, but the one in [Linus Torvalds' description](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) is `--no-ff`.  I think the most memorable is the `--force-rebase` version, but I would actually use `-f` myself.)

Let's take a fast look at both, and then consider which to use and why.  In either case, once you are done, you'll have to merge the new commit(s) correctly this time, without removing files; but now that you know what `git merge` is really doing, it should be a lot easier to do.

We start by creating a new branch name.  We can re-use `branch-F`, but I think it is clearer if we don't.  If we want to use `git merge --squash`, we create this new branch name pointing to commit `T0` (ignoring the fact that there are commits after `T0`—remember, any branch name can point to *any* commit):

```
T0   <-- revised-F (HEAD)
 \
  F0--fc1--fc2--M1   <-- branch-F
```

If we want to use `git rebase -f`, we create this new name pointing to commit `fc2`:

```
T0-----....
 \
  F0--fc1--fc2--M1   <-- branch-F, revised-F (HEAD)
```

We do this with:

```
git checkout -b revised-F <hash of T0>   # for merge --squash method
```

or:

```
git checkout -b revised-f branch-F^1      # for rebase -f method
```

depending on which method we want to use.  (The `^1` or `~1` suffix—you can use either one—excludes `M1` itself, stepping back one first-parent step to `fc2`.  The idea here is to exclude commit `o` and any other commits reachable from `o`.  There need to be no other merges into `branch-F` along that bottom row of commits, here.)

Now, if we want to use a "squash merge" (which uses Git's merge machinery without making a merge *commit*), we run:

```
git merge --squash branch-F
```

This uses our current commit, plus the tip of `branch-F` (commit `M1`), as the left and right sides of the merge, finding their common commit as the merge base.  The common commit is of course just `F0`, so the merge *result* is the snapshot in `M1`.  However, the new commit made has only *one* parent: it is not a merge commit at all, and it looks like this:

```
   fc1--fc2--M1   <-- branch-F
  /
F0-------------F3   <-- revised-F (HEAD)
```

The *snapshot* in `F3` matches that in `M1`, but the commit itself is all new.  It gets a new commit message (which you may edit) and its effect, when Git looks at `F3` as a commit, is to make the same set of changes made from `F0` to `M1`.

If we choose the rebase method, we now run:

```
git rebase -f <hash-of-T0>
```

(You could use instead the hash of `o`, which is `branch-F^2`, i.e., the second parent of `M1`.  In this case you can start with `revised-F` pointing to `M1` itself.  That's probably what I would do, to avoid having to cut and paste a lot of hash IDs with potential typos, but it's not obvious how this works unless you've done a lot of graph manipulation exercises.)

That is, we want to copy commits `F0` through `fc2` inclusive to *new* commits, with new hash IDs.  That's what this `git rebase` will do (see other StackOverflow answers and/or Linus' description above): we get:

```
  F0'-fc1'-fc2'   <-- revised-F (HEAD)
 /
T0-----....
 \
  F0--fc1--fc2--M1   <-- branch-F
```

Now that we have `revised-F` pointing to either a single commit (`F3`) or a chain of commits (the chain ending at `fc2'`, the copy of `fc2`), we can `git checkout` some other branch and `git merge revised-F`.

## Based on comments, here are two paths for doing the re-merge

I assume at this point that you have a squash-merge result (a single-parent commit that's not a merge, but does contain the desired snapshot, which I'm calling `F3` here).  We need to revise the re-drawn graph a bit too, based on comments that indicate there were more merges into `branch-F`:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4---R1---M5---sc5   <-- branch-S
  \                        \  /         /
   T0-----o-------o----M2---M3--------R2   <---- branch-T1
    \      \       \  /
    F0--fc1-o-fc2---M1   <--------------- branch-F
```

Now we'll add the `revised-F` branch, which should have a single commit that is a descendant of either `F0` or `T0`.  It's not crucial which one.  Since I used `F0` earlier, let's go with that here:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4---R1---M5---sc5   <-- branch-S
  \                        \  /         /
   T0-----o-------o----M2---M3--------R2   <---- branch-T1
    \      \       \  /
    F0--fc1-o-fc2---M1   <--------------- branch-F
      \
       ---------------------------------F3   <-- revised-F
```

The contents of commit `F3` match those of `M1` (so `git diff branch-F revised-F` says nothing), but the parent of `F3` here is `F0`.  (Note: there are shortcut ways to create `F3` using `git commit-tree`, but as long as it already exists and matches `M1` content-wise, we can just use it.)

If we now do:

```
git checkout branch-T1
git merge revised-F
```

Git will find the merge base between commit `R2` (tip of branch-T1) and `F3` (tip of `revised-F`).  If we follow all the backwards (leftwards) links from `R2`, we can get to `T0` via `M3` then `M2` then some number of `o`s and finally `T0`, or we can get to `F0` via `M3` then `M2` then `M1` then `fc2` on back to `F0`.  Meanwhile we can get from `F3` straight to `F0`, in just one hop, so the merge base is probably `F0`.

(To confirm this, use `git merge-base`:

```
git merge-base --all branch-T1 revised-F
```

This will print one or more hash IDs, one for each merge base.  Ideally there's just the one merge base, which is commit `F0`.)

Git will now run the two `git diff`s, to compare the contents of `F0` to `F3`—i.e., everything we did to accomplish the feature—and to compare the contents of `F0` to those of `R2`, at the tip of `branch-T1`.  We'll get conflicts where both diffs change the same lines of the same files.  Elsewhere, Git will take the contents of `F0`, apply the combined changes, and leave the result ready to be committed (in the index).

Resolving these conflicts and committing will give you a new commit that results in:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4---R1---M5---sc5   <-- branch-S
  \                        \  /         /
   T0-----o-------o----M2---M3--------R2-----M6   <---- branch-T1
    \      \       \  /                     /
    F0--fc1-o-fc2---M1   <-- branch-F      /
      \                                   /
       ---------------------------------F3   <-- revised-F
```

Now `M6` is, perhaps, merge-able to `branch-S`.

---

Alternatively, we can merge directly to `branch-S`.  It's less obvious which commit is the merge base, but it is probably `F0` again.  Here is the same drawing again:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4---R1---M5---sc5   <-- branch-S
  \                        \  /         /
   T0-----o-------o----M2---M3--------R2   <---- branch-T1
    \      \       \  /
    F0--fc1-o-fc2---M1   <--------------- branch-F
      \
       ---------------------------------F3   <-- revised-F
```

Starting from commit `sc5`, we work backwards to `M5` to `R2`, and we're now in the same situation we were before.  So we can `git checkout branch-S` and do the same merge, resolve similar conflicts—this time we're comparing `F0` to `sc5` rather than to `R2`, so the conflicts might be slightly different—and eventually commit:

```
S0--sc1---sc2---sc3-----sc4----M4---R1---M5---sc5----M6   <-- branch-S
  \                        \  /         /           /
   T0-----o-------o----M2---M3--------R2   <------ / -- branch-T1
    \      \       \  /                           /
    F0--fc1-o-fc2---M1   <-- branch-F            /
      \                                         /
       ---------------------------------------F3   <-- revised-F
```

To verify that `F0` is the merge base, use `git merge-base` as before:

```
git merge-base --all branch-S revised-F
```

and to see what you'd have to merge, run two `git diff`s from the merge base to the two tips.

(Which merge to do is up to you.)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this very detailed explanation and answer! You've shown me that I am 100% in the wrong frame of mind with Git. I'm working on doing the rebase now, but since `T0` was from about two months ago I am working through a ton of merge conflicts. I'm about halfway through all of them - I'll let you know if this works.

Comment: When you do the branch copy, you should get *no* merge conflicts: if you're getting merge conflicts, you're picking up commits you don't want (through merges that weren't shown in the `F0--fc1--fc2` chain, but must actually be in there). In this case you might use the squash method, or a carefully hand-built list of commits for cherry-pick. This is why (and when) the exact graph is critical: commit lists are based on walking the graph, and the "reachability" notion.

Comment: Or: maybe they're being picked up through `M1`, in which case you want to start with `revised-F` pointing to `fc2`. I should fix the above

Comment: No you're right, there were a few points in the history of `branch-F` where `branch-T1` was merged in. This feature branch spanned some time because I was pulled off the project a couple times and I forgot that I had performed that merge before `M1`. In this case, should I just abandon the rebase and start a squash? I assume there are downsides to attempting to resolve all of these conflicts.

Comment: The disadvantage to doing the one-big-squash and re-merge is that it makes it harder to find bugs later using `git bisect`. The advantage is that it's way easier to deal with right now. The rebase-or-cherry-pick method (which preserves the original work via copy) requires enumerating the set of commits to copy. Just how hard that is, depends on how careful all the merges were: it's possible that `git rev-list --topo-order --reverse --first-parent <cutoff>..<endpoint>` will produce the correct list. This walks the graph, but follows only the first parent of each merge. (continued)

Comment: Once you have the correct list, in (say) a file of hash IDs, you could cherry-pick them all. It's still tricky since any merge has to be accounted for. That's a fair bit of work, and probably not worth the price for the potential future gain, so at this point I'd go for the squash-merge-then-re-merge method.

Comment: Thank you again for that explanation! Given the amount of commits I had gone through, how many were left, and how unsure I was with how I was resolving the conflicts, I began attempting the squash merge. See Edit 2 above in the original question - I am now thinking I need to merge `revised-F` directly up to `branch-S` but there are a lot of changes (and conflicts) when I attempt to do this. My missing changes from `revised-F` are in there, though.

Comment: There definitely will be conflicts (which will require manual resolution) when merging `revised-F`. Merging to `branch-T1` should help (I think). Let me draw this in as an edit... it's easier to see when there's a drawing!

Comment: I just wanted to leave a comment to say huge thank you to @torek! Such a great and detailed answer! I learned a lot from it!